# Id column in schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Everytimes, I have a column for my event object (event-calendar gem) in my schema.rb file

```
t.integer  "id", :null => false
```

So of course, every time I want to create an event I have an error "null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint" because of this. I tried this solution [ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059283/activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror-error-null-value-in-column-id-viol) but it appears everytimes !!! I would like to know WHY this column appears here, I really don't understand...

Any idea ?

Comment: How did you install it? What version of Rails? Did you have an existing event model?

Comment: Rails 3 and yes, it is an existing event. But sometimes, schema.rb is modified with this values and I don't know how and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created the events model, it sounds like you added an id field. This isn't necessary as rails automatically creates this field. Your event model in your schema should look something like:

```
create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
end
```

I would rollback the migration, assuming this is the most recent migration:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Then update the migration file and remove the id from the create_table block:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
   end
end
```

Then rerun the migration.