# inserting in model works in development but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am stuck in really weird issue. i have the following code in my `SessionsController`

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      @history=user.histories.build(:TimeLogin => Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
      @history.save
      redirect_back_or "/recalls"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

i am trying to save login time in my `History` model. this works fine at development environment. but when i add my work to heroku i get the following error in logs

```
2013-10-29T06:47:29.542675+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
2013-10-29T06:47:29.542675+00:00 app[web.1]: DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 2013-10-29 06:47:00, null, 1, 2013-10-29 06:47:29.533033, 2013-10-29 06:47:29.533033).
2013-10-29T06:47:29.542675+00:00 app[web.1]: : INSERT INTO "histories" ("TimeLogin", "TimeLogout", "created_at", "id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)):
2013-10-29T06:47:29.542675+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

please guide me what i am doing wrong? i am unable to figure out because same works at my dev site
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe ActiveRecord has an issue with `CamelCase` field names? Just a guess though, as the error suggests the `id` column is missing.

Comment: THe same error as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059283/activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror-error-null-value-in-column-id-viol Does that help?

Comment: @nathanvda i already have seen that link. this is not the case with me, as i checked and compared my history schema. i guess i am giving some null, value, trying to figure out.

Comment: Normally you never fill in the id yourself, so I am guessing it is somewhere in your schema defined wrong. Unless you normally do fill in the id yourself, but then you would do it in development as well. The only difference between development and production, in this case, is your database. And the error clearly states the `id` is null.

Comment: Can you add history migration also in your question...

Comment: And on a side note: the camelcased field names are not ruby naming convention: that is going to bite you later on.

Comment: well i caught my issue. i have created `id Serial` and in model i forgot to  add `set_primary_key :id`. Thanks to all for guiding. @Thahakp comment helped me alot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the issue by adding
`set_primary_key :id` 
to my model, as in migration i created `id` as `SERIAL`